# 14.10 Software Updater not updating

Tags: updates, update-manager, gnome-terminal

I am using Ubuntu 14.10.

To keep things as brief as possible:

1. Software Updater -

   (a) This runs, tells me I need updates, I give permissions to update, it then tells me I have no internet connection.

   (b) Previously to the last update, it worked fine, last update ceased suddenly after something network or driver related had been updated, since then I have had this report of no internet when I do have internet.

   (c) Today it reports I need to install 269MiB of updates, the very same updates that have been updated prior to the update that killed internet in software updater and just downloaded by terminal however this seems to not be registering with software updater.

   (d) Consequently I can not update via this service.
2. Terminal -

   (a) This downloads the updates without a problem. I used the `sudo apt-get update` command and `sudo apt-get install`

   (b) It is not installing updates, it reports something that I didn't take much notice of other than it had wording like "nothing to install" or maybe install was update, well something along those lines. Yet there is something to install because stuff was downloaded and if it is not needed then that is wasting my data allowance TYVM which is costly as any mobile tether on a PAYG service can tell you hardliners. Grrrr.

   (c) see 1.(d)

So how can I work this situation, no matter what approach I take its not working so all the suggested avenues I have looked at, all relater to a specific program, however in my case the specific program is software updater related, if their is a subject or link that I am not aware of, please feel free to point me in that direction.

** EDIT **

For some unknown reason, a situation that left me unable to update by Software  Updater and also via terminal, each with opposing problems, suddenly updated itself without rhyme or reason...

So the questions now are

1. how can a computer update itself without authorization?
2. how can a locked situation become unraveled before my very eyes without any intervention by me?

Comment: The question is not clear. Why can't you update using Software Updater? You run a wrong command. It is not `sudo apt-get install` it is `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: It is clear enough that software updater is not updating because it keeps on telling me that I have no Internet when I do (see 1(a) )... also I am looking to install updates, not upgrade.

Comment: @MarkGiblin An update is what Ubuntu and Debian call upgrade. Upgrade simply means "Getting new versions of packages which you have installed." btw. dist-upgrade means the same, but it installs new packages if dependencies change. It doesn't mean going to the next release. And `apt-get install <pkgname>` mean installing the package pkgname which is not yet installes. That's not what you want. Read the `man apt-get`

Comment: @DanielAlder, Well, its done it by itself and like every install I have had, some things are not working properly...

Answer (score 0):

As described in my comment: `apt-get install` is for installing software which is not yet present on your computer. For doing the same job as update-manager does, you have to run `apt-get upgrade` i personally prefer `apt-get dist-upgrade` because it also installs kernel upgrades etc. Probably update-manager acts more like dist-upgrade. `man apt-get` is a good help page...

Now to the answers of your questions:

#### 1. how can a computer update itself without authorization?

update-manager (the gui tool). Works only as a front-end. In the background there is aptd which is triggered by systemd. If you want to run updates, update-manager tells aptd over systemd to run the updates, while aptd is running as root.

The permission check itself is technically not necessary: While starting update-manager, it also asks aptd via systemd for which you won't be asked for a password.

For the auto updates, you should have a look at the script `/etc/cron.daily/apt` which runs as root once per day.

The process list while updates get installed shows something like this:

```
14537 ?        SNl    0:02   /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/aptd
14625 pts/57   SNs+   0:00     /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/aptd
14661 pts/58   DNs+   0:00       /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 43 --unpack --auto-deconfigure /var/cache/apt/archives/freshplayerp....deb
```

#### 2. how can a locked situation become unraveled before my very eyes without any intervention by me?

The locking probably comes from the apt-get update above, or from another test. It resolved by itself because it just finished its job.

For checking this, you can run the following command while apt-get is locked:

```
ps ax | grep apt
```